# Date conversion to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need in PostgreSQL.

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+(TO_NUMBER(puttim)/86400),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

[image]

I've tried the below code but that's not giving desired output. Value must be with the current_timestamp with extra 2 seconds.

```
to_char(current_timestamp + (puttim::integer) * INTERVAL '2 second', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS');
```

Comment: So what does this code do? And why are you storing numbers in a varchar column?

Comment: The difference between `00:00:00` and `00:00:02` is two **seconds** not two milliseconds. But it's still unclear to me what that oracle code is supposed to do. What unit does `settime` represent? Seconds? Milliseconds. And if it's number then why need the cast?

Answer (score 1):

From here [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-formatting.html)

> to_number ( text, text ) → numeric

> Converts string to numeric according to the given format. to_number('12,454.8-', '99G999D9S') → -12454.8.

You need to provide a number format. See the rest of the link for what those are.

If `settime` is actually all number characters you can skip the formatting and do:

```
select '1234'::integer, '1.25'::numeric;
 int4 | numeric 
------+---------
 1234 |    1.25
```

So something like:

`settime::integer/86400`

Comment: Why do you need my email? If this answer helps will you up vote  and/or accept it?

Comment: Your best option is to join the [pgsql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/list/) mailing list. The link has instructions on how to sign up.

Comment: That information is at the [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-formatting.html) link in Table 9.26. Template Patterns for Date/Time Formatting

Answer (score 0):

That should be simple with date arithmetic:

```
to_char(clock_timestamp() + settime * INTERVAL '1 second', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```